# Xen on openSUSE 11.4

Tags: opensuse, virtual-machine, xen

I have done a few installs of openSUSE to use as a Xen dom0 and have not got it working yet. These are the steps I followed:

1. Installed openSUSE 11.4 from Live KDE CD.
2. Installed all updates via YaST>Package Management.
3. Installed Xen via YaST>Install Hypervisor (installed all xen and kernel packages required).
4. Reboot into Xen kernel.

After this if I go into YaST>Create Virtual Machine I can specify all the relevant options for my first VM (domU) but when I click finish I get this error:

`Failed to start vm-install`

If I then go into YaST>Virtual machine Manager then right click the Xen Hypervisor and click Connect I get the following errors:

```
Unable to open a connection to the Xen hypervisor/daemon.

Verify that:
- A Xen host kernel was booted
- The Xen service has been started
```

and

```
unable to connect to 'localhost:8000': Connection refused

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 983, in _try_open
None], flags)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 107, in openAuth
if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: unable to connect to 'localhost:8000': Connection refused
```

I am definitely in the correct Kernel and all processes appear to be started as per:

```
kaon:/home/danny # uname -a
Linux kaon.cybertron.local 2.6.37.6-0.7-xen #1 SMP 2011-07-21 02:17:24 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
kaon:/home/danny # ps -ef | grep xen
root 15 2 0 19:54 ? 00:00:00 [xenwatch]
root 16 2 0 19:54 ? 00:00:00 [xenbus]
root 1735 1 0 19:55 ? 00:00:00 xenstored
root 1742 1 0 19:55 ? 00:00:00 xenconsoled --pid-file=/var/run/xenconsoled.pid
root 2017 1 0 19:55 ? 00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/xend start
root 2019 2017 0 19:55 ? 00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/xend start
root 2975 2956 0 20:00 pts/1 00:00:00 grep xen
```

I have posted this issue on the openSUSE forums [here](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/463822-cannot-install-domu.html) but no one has been able to help.

The only other thing I've found Google searching that relates to this error is a mismatch between the versions of xen and xen-tools installed which I have confirmed is not my case, both packages have matching versions as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chkconfig xencommons off
reboot
```

Comment: What is xencommons (a service - but what does it do badly)?